# .NET Core MVC Form returning wrong model value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm having a weird issue with a form in my View not returning the model's correct Id property value. You'll noticed in the code below I have the script section logging the model's Id. Doing this shows the correct Id on the console, but when the Id is passed to the Controller's action method it is always 0, which is incorrect.

Here's the view:

```
@model EotE_Encounter.Models.Encounter

<div>
    <h4>@Model.Name</h4>
    <div>
        <form asp-action="CreateCharacter" asp-controller="Encounter" data-bind="" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#character-container">
            <input id="encounterId" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create Character</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <ul>

            @{
                if(Model.CharactersInEncounter != null)
                {
                    foreach(Character character in Model.CharactersInEncounter)
                    {
                        <li>@character.Name</li>
                    }
                }
            }        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    console.log(@Model.Id);
</script>
```

Related Action Method:

```
public ActionResult CreateCharacter(int encounterID)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("CreateCharacter", "Character", encounterID);
        }
```

And the Encounter model:

```
 public class Encounter
    {
        //these first three properties may not be used just yet.
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte Round { get; set; }
        public List<Character> CharactersInEncounter { get; set; }
        [StringLength(2000)]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Add your model classes and related action methods to the question please..

Comment: Just added them. :)

Comment: Ok..Now tell me what id value your are expecting?

Comment: The Id value is created when I add the Encounter to the DB. But for example, the Id was once 16008. This was logged on the console, so I'm pretty sure the model is being passed to the view correctly. However, when the form calls its associated action method, the Id is always 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where is your get method that retrieving the entity from the database?

Comment: Spectarion was able to solve my problem. I evidently had a typo, and I needed the name attribute. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form. So, add the **name** attribute to your hidden element. **Id and the name are not the same**.

```
@model EotE_Encounter.Models.Encounter

<div>
    <h4>@Model.Name</h4>
    <div>
        <form asp-action="CreateCharacter" asp-controller="Encounter" data-bind="" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#character-container">
            <input id="encounterId" name="encounterID" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Create Character</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <ul>

            @{
                if(Model.CharactersInEncounter != null)
                {
                    foreach(Character character in Modelsel.CharactersInEncounter)
                    {
                        <li>@character.Name</li>
                    }
                }
            }        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    console.log(@Model.Id);
</script>
```

Notice the **name attribute** of the `<input id="encounterId" name="encounterID" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />` element. It has to be the same name as the action parameter (`int encounterID`). If it's not the same then the parameter binding will not work.

Comment: Not only did I have a typo, which you helped point out, but adding the name attribute did the trick. Thank you!